# cause sql injection

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, code-injection

I am learning sql injections and very interested how to cause this.
I have written script to see how it is going. so here is my code =>

```
if (isset($_POST['act'])){
    if ($connection = mysqli_connect($var['host'],$var['user'],$var['password'],$var['database'])){
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()==0){
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['pswd'];
            if ($result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT username,password FROM login WHERE username='" . $username . "' AND password='" . $password . "'")){
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result)){
                    header("Location: http://localhost/default.php");
                } else {
                    $res = "Invalid Credentials ...";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

<form name="action" method="post" action="index.php">
    Username:<input type="text" name="username" size="12"><br>
    Password:<input type="password" name="pswd" size=12><br>
    <input type="submit" name="act" value="Login">
</form>
```

I'm writing like this in forms, but nothing happening

in username and in password form =>  some' OR '1'='1'

I'm very interested how to cause sql injection to break this script and without valid credentials redirect to default.php (of course within from marked script)

Thanks ...

Comment: nothing I means that, it is not writing "Invalid Credentials" and also do not redirecting. I think it is happening sql error, but it can not be shown in script

Comment: Have you tried entering your username as `' or 1=1` and setting your password to just `'` in your form?

Comment: In that case you should at least add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your code, so that we can see any errors returned by your code

Comment: yeah, nothing special :(, now i try error_reporting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try entering `' OR 1 --` as username

Also, just in case, chack if you have `magic_quotes_gpc` disabled :)

Comment: Didn't you meant `OR 1 = 1 --`?

Comment: @DaHaKa -- is a comment in SQL.

Comment: `--` is a beginning of a comment. Anything after `--` is ignored by MySQL (until end od line)

Comment: understand but without -- i can not cause what i wanted and why ?

Comment: I have one question too , when i am writing in username: ' OR 1 -- and in password: ' works, but why it is not working on the contrary ?

Comment: Because when you add the --, the password part is ignored by SQL.

Comment: DaHaKa: Imagine how your query look like when you do it my way:
`SELECT username,password FROM login WHERE username='' OR 1 --'  AND password='''` - anything after `--` is ignored, so it's a valid query. In your case it looks like `SELECT username,password FROM login WHERE username=''' AND password='' OR 1 --'` now you have unapaired quotes, so entire query is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Have u watched this ? Pretty basic, but interesting if you r new to SQL injections
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bORZlmyDw0s